# What makes Alex Rider and Matthew Freeman so different?

Tags: anthony-horowitz, alex-rider, the-gatekeepers

At the end of my copy of *Raven's Gate*, there's a Q&A with Anthony Horowitz, the author. One of the questions is:

> **Q**: *Is it difficult to write both Alex Rider and The Gatekeepers at the same time? What do you think the series have in common, and what's different?*
>
> **A**: I can't write Alex Rider at the same time as The Gatekeepers - the two are just too different. Fortunately, I've now finished the sixth Alex adventure, *Ark Angel*, and don't plan to return to him until I've finished the second and third volumes of The Gatekeepers series.
> What do the two series have in common? Pace, adventure, action, violence, and, I hope, readability. They're both fairly adult - not classic "children's books". But Matt Freeman is no Alex Rider. He's much less sure of himself, even more of a victim than Alex. And there won't be quite so many happy endings in The Gatekeepers.

But what are some examples of Matt being less sure of himself? In what other ways are they different?